# Constructing transitive matrices

Tags: c++, matrix

I am trying to construct a program that firstly  randomly generates an upper quadrant matrix (defined as  'transmatrix') with integer values of 0 and 1. Next I want to analysis each element of this matrix. If there is a 1 in the i,j-th entry of the transmatrix then I want a new matrix defined as 'forwardarray' to have a randomly generated value between 1 and 10 in the same entry position. If there is a zero in the i,j-th entry of the transmatrix I want the program to check and if both the k,i-th and k,j-th entry are not zero (ie test for transitivity). If both are not zero than for position i,j-th in the forwardarray should have a randomly generated value between 1 and 10. If one is zero, than generate a random number, rnd, between 0 and 1 see if it is less than 0.9. If rnd is less than 0.9 then the i,j-th entry in the forwardarray should be a randomly gnerated number from 0 to 10. If the rnd is greater than 0.9 than i,j-th position in the forwardarray should equal zero.
The problem is that the output for the 'forwardarray' is not an upper quadrant matrix. Could anyone try and point me in the right direction?
My code is:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>


using namespace std;


int main()

{  ofstream outFile;
   outFile.open("array.dat");

   srand(time(NULL));

   int noofpeople=4;
   outFile << noofpeople << endl;
   outFile << endl;

   int happinesslevels[noofpeople];
   for(int a=0; a<noofpeople; a++)
   {
   happinesslevels[a]=(rand() % 101);      
   outFile << happinesslevels[a] << " ";
   }
   outFile << endl;

/* Generate upper quadrant transmatrix */

double rnd=((double)rand()/RAND_MAX);
int transmatrix[noofpeople][noofpeople];
 for(int b=0; b<noofpeople; b++) {
    for (int c=b+1; c<noofpeople; c++) {
transmatrix[b][c]=(rand() % 2);
          outFile << transmatrix[b][c] << " ";
        }
    outFile << endl;
 }

double forwardarray[noofpeople][noofpeople];
  for(int k=0; k<noofpeople;k++)
  {
      for(int i=k+1; i<noofpeople;i++)
      {
         for(int j=i+1; j<noofpeople;j++)
         {
             if (transmatrix[k][i]==1)
                forwardarray[k][i]=(rand() % 10 + 1);
            else if (transmatrix[k][i]!=1) {
                    if ((transmatrix[k][j]==1) && (transmatrix[i][j]==1))
                forwardarray[k][i]=(rand() % 10 + 1);
                else if  ((transmatrix[k][j]==0) || (transmatrix[i][j]==0)) {
                if (rnd<=0.9)
                forwardarray[k][i]=(rand() % 11);
                else
                forwardarray[k][i]=0;
               }
           }
    outFile << forwardarray[k][i] << " ";

    outFile << endl;
         }
      }

  }
}
```

The data that I get is

```
4

81 37 86 36 
0 0 1 
0 0 
1 

2 
9 
3 
0
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by the "upper quadrant matrix"? Because I can see in the code, that you're creating a square matrix i.e. matrix in which numbers of rows and columns are equal. I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve, this description seems to be very confusing and the source is too large - you need only the shortest sample that depicts the problem.

I've made some changes in the code - if..else if can be replaced by if..else and the indentation doesn't help in reading. After moving the writing instructions from the most inner loop, I was able to get an "upper quadrant matrix", but I don't know if this is what you're looking for. The description of an algorithm requires more clarification about the role of "k".

```cpp
for(int k=0; k<noofpeople;k++)
{
    for(int i=k+1; i<noofpeople;i++)
    {
         for(int j=i; j<noofpeople;j++)
         {
             if (transmatrix[k][i]==1) {
                 forwardarray[k][i]=(rand() % 10 + 1);
             } else {
                 if ((transmatrix[k][j]==1) && (transmatrix[i][j]==1)) {
                     forwardarray[k][i]=(rand() % 10 + 1);
                 } else {
                     if (rnd<=0.9)
                         forwardarray[k][i]=(rand() % 11);
                     else
                         forwardarray[k][i]=0;
                 }
             }
         }
         outFile << forwardarray[k][i] << " ";
    }
    outFile << endl;
}
```